# Исправить ещё что-нибудь в сообщении?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, правки

Сегодня пытался исправить один вопрос, вылезло вот это:

> Минимальная длина правки 6 символов; исправить ещё что-нибудь в
>   сообщении?

Когда читаешь это, кажется, что SO спрашивает, нужно ли ему исправить что-нибудь ещё в сообщении. Я думаю, это следует немного подправить.

Comment: давайте просто уберем это ограничение - оно подбешивает

Comment: @michael_best Хотелось бы, да уже поздно, весь SE такой.

Comment: мы можем поставить минимальную длину в 1 символ?

Comment: @michael_best насколько я знаю, это общее ограничение для всех сайтов SE. Но даже, если где-то настраивается, то различий между разными SO точно быть не должно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Edits must be at least $MinBodyDiffLength$ characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

ИМХО, ключевое в сообщении - призыв поискать и поправить что-нибудь еще.
Предлагаю вот такой перевод:

> Правка должна быть не менее $MinBodyDiffLength$ символов; может быть в сообщении можно исправить что-нибудь ещё?

---

По предложению αλεχολυτ:

> ".. может быть в сообщении можно исправить или улучшить что-нибудь ещё?"

т.е. мы призываем, что даже если все уже исправлено, но это все равно меньше 6 символов, то попробовать еще и что-нибудь улучшить.

Comment: Почему «исправить», если там «улучшить»?

Comment: Кнопка "правка", мы правим. Так менее дословно, но по смыслу, мне кажется, точнее.

Comment: просто сообщение можно дополнить/сократить, не исправляя его, а именно улучшая. Добавить деталей (из комментов, скажем), или убрать «приветствия и спасибы».

Comment: Как насчет *".. может быть в сообщении можно исправить или улучшить что-нибудь ещё?"* - т.е. мы призываем, что даже если все уже исправлено, но это все равно меньше 6 символов, то попробовать еще и что-нибудь улучшить.

Comment: я не сторонник искажения смысла при переводе, если честно. Но могу допускать такое неявно :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ратую за то, чтобы перевод передавал смысл, а не был дословной калькой. Спасибо за замечание. Вероятно уже оставлю так, а дальше пусть голосование и ответственное лицо решают, что выбрать

Comment: Голосование не нужно (ц) :-D

Comment: Утвердил гибридный вариант.

Answer (score 5):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/573

Там в оригинале:

> Edits must be at least $MinBodyDiffLength$ characters; is there
>   something else to improve in this post?

Предлагаю:

> Минимальная длина правки $MinBodyDiffLength$ символов; хотите
>   исправить что-нибудь ещё?

Comment: Почему «исправить», если там «улучшить»?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ потому что не факт, что они улучшают :D

Comment: то есть перевод мы тоже исправляем, а не улучшаем? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ для кого-то это улучшение, для кого-то нет, но для всех, совершенно точно, это исправление ^_^"

Comment: всё же исправление подразумевает ошибку в исходном состоянии, а улучшение можно воспринять несколько шире. Например, добавить новой инфы или перефразировать. То есть не обязательно быть ошибке в оригинале.

Answer (score 3):

Дополню ответ @Ver Nick

Сообществу не кажется, что вопрос тут неуместен?

> ".. может быть в сообщении можно исправить или улучшить что-нибудь
>   ещё?"

- Нет, нельзя

> "...исправить ещё что-нибудь в сообщении?"

- Ну исправь

Смахивает на общение - но тут "общение" c машиной не реализовано

Система не позволяет исправить меньше 6 символов, значит должна быть просьба

> Минимальная длина правки 6 символов; исправьте/улучшите ещё что-нибудь
>   в сообщении

Answer (score 1):

> Минимальная длина правки 6 символов; исправьте что-нибудь ещё в
>   сообщении.

Comment: Почему «исправить», если там «улучшить»?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну и что? Мы же не должны полностью копировать enSO.

Comment: смысл-то разный

Answer (score 1):

> Edits must be at least $MinBodyDiffLength$ characters; is there
>   something else to improve in this post?

Предлагаю «improve» всё же переводить как «улучшение»:

> Правки должны затрагивать хотя бы $MinBodyDiffLength$ символов; есть ли в сообщении что-то ещё для улучшения?